# Do any sects that do not subscribe to advaita believe in the concept of Maya?

Tags: advaita, maya

Instead of the popular meaning illusion, I like the definition from

http://vedantastudent.blogspot.com/p/maya.html

"Maya creates apparent multiplicity in a universe where only Brahman really exists."

Does this clash with dualistic sects?

Comment: Maya is scriptural term. It's found in the Upanishads, in the Tantras as well as in the Puranas. So, no one can really disregard Maya. It is not a term that was invented by an Advaitic scholar. I can add an answer too that it is there in other sects but not in the same way.

Comment: please do @rickross